# formatting issue on ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, css, formatting

Scenario: I want to display the following through ASPX page

```
 State : <dropdown>
   zip : <textbutton>
```

Note that the ":" for both State & City should be same in all lines.  Currently I am getting something below.

```
 State : <dropdown>
 zip : <textbutton>
```

I must be doing something wrong but don't know yet. Appreciate any inputs,

Here is my code so far,

```
<div style="text-align:center" >
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StateCategory" Text ="State:" CssClass="LabelLeftAligned" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="StateDDown" DataTextField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center" >
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblzipCode" Text ="Zip:" CssClass="LabelLeftAligned" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtboxZipcode" runat="server" MaxLength="5" />
</div>
```

and the class LabelLeftAligned is defined below in the stylesheet.

```
.LabelLeftAligned {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: What are you using to build that display? CSS or a table?

Comment: It is CSS. I am mostly using DIV tags only.

Comment: Your sample shows a right aligned label, but your css code is left aligned...  Which is it that you are really after?

Comment: I just put that 'text-align:left' to see if it works. But my expectations are as described in the original post. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the label into a block level element, give it a width and right align it.

Something like: (full example)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<style> 
  .LabelRightAligned { 
    display:block; 
    width: 150px; 
    text-align:right; 
    float:left; 
  } 


  .ddl { 
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px; 
  } 
</style> 

</head>

<body>

<div style="text-align:center;clear:both;">  
    <span class="LabelRightAligned">State:</span>
    <select class="ddl">
        <option value="volvo" />
        <option value="chevy" />
    </select>
</div> 
<div style="text-align:center;clear:both;">  
    <span class="LabelRightAligned">zip:</span>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="23423" class="ddl" />
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

example below:

[image]

Comment: How does this produce the desired result? The second row will not align with the first...

Comment: @JamesJohnson: just put a full example, and yes, it aligns.

Comment: Removed downvote. Still wondering how I was downvoted though, as I provided a working jsFiddle. Have any guesses?

Comment: @JamesJohnson: I have no guesses.  However, if your actions on this question are anything to go by, I'd say you probably torqued someone on another question and they have "revenge" voted you.  Either way, SO accounts for that and corrects the points every so often so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table formatting in CSS to achieve this. You would use `layout` for your rows and cells, and `text-align` to control the horizontal alignment.

**Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwVYg/2/) for a working demonstration.**

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.table {  
    display:table;  
    border-collapse:collapse;  
}       
.table-row {  
    display:table-row;  
}       
.left-col {
    text-align:right; 
}    
.right-col {
    text-align:left; 
}    
.left-col, .right-col {  
    display:table-cell;  
}         
</style> 

<div class="table">  
    <div class="table-row">  
        <div class="left-col">  
            Foobar:  
        </div>  
        <div class="right-col">  
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
        </div>  
    </div> 
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="left-col">  
            Bar:  
        </div>  
        <div class="right-col">  
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTestB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me in above example under which DIV tag will "State:" and "StateDropdown" needs to be placed? sorry if it is simple question.

Comment: I tried above and I am getting this display. "state" towards extreme right and then on next line textbutton which is left aligned.  Any ideas? Also in your css above, where is defination for "table" class? did u mean that as "content-body-wrapper". also we have not used ".left-col, .right-col" in the code? please suggest.

Comment: I tried that but no success. Basically the very first line has "State:" to the extreme right of the line and then in second line to the extreme left is the text button. Also I want to have "State:" <textbutton> to the centre of page. this applies to other lines such as zip and others as well? thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I didn't do a downvote. I am still evaluating my entire CSS used in that ASPX page.

Comment: You sure go through a lot of work just to mimick what a table already gives you.

Comment: OP asked for a CSS solution, so I provided one. The benefit of this solution is that you don't need to specify a width for the left column, as the the left column in the other rows will scale the width of the widest column. It also has the benefit of rendering faster than a table, but still behaving like one.

Comment: Although I'm not proposing tables, I'd argue that the above is actually slower for a browser to display than a table with the layout:fixed style and hard set width values.  Under yours, the browser still needs to compute the actual widths; which is where most of the time is spent.  Although, for this limited dataset the difference is marginal at best.

Comment: @James/Chris:Both solution worked but is allowing me to mark anyone answer. Can't I mark both ?

Comment: I have marked Chris answer as it allowed only one. Although James answer also worked but it takes only one.

Answer (score -1):

either table the data which in this case shouldn't be a problem based on the little bit I am seeing

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>State</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><dropdown></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zip</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><textbutton></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

OR

wrap the state and zip in a div and then float it left with a width on it

```
<div class="floatLeft">State</div> : <dropdown>
<div class="floatLeft">Zip</div> : <textbutton>

<style>
 .floatLeft {float: left; width: 300px; }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried with floatLeft and this is what I am seeing. "State:" and "zip:" are not aligned (I mean the ":"). Also I want the entire "State : <dropdown>" to be centre aligned.

Comment: Shouldn't be using float for this kind of stuff anymore. That's what `layout` is for. See my answer.

Comment: -1: After looking at it again, your solution does not answer the question. OP stated that they wanted to achieve this without tables if possible.

Comment: @Anirudh actual the float left was a class not just float: left;  so it needed to be float: left with a width of XXXpx and then applied to all divs that are in that column.

Comment: @JamesJohnson the OP did not state when I responded whether they wanted tables or not.